# Remove all divs except first div for the selected id elements in jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Requirement is to keep the heading - head1 and head2 and  first div element which comes after heading head1 and head2 id and delete all other heading and div elements. 
Please look in to the expected output can give you a clear idea on my requirement.

Input HTML:

```
 <html>
  <head> ...</head>
  <body> 
   <div id="main-content">
    <div class ="abc">sample data </div>

   <h1 id="head1">Example 1 </h1>
   <div class="abc"> 
      <table> <tr><td> table data 1</td></tr></table>
    </div>
   <div class="abc"> extra div </div>
   <div class="abc"> one more extra div </div>

   <h1 id="head2">Example 2</h1>
   <div class="abc"> 
      <table> 
        <tr><td> table data 2</td></tr>
     </table>
   </div>
  <div class="abc">extra div </div>
  <div class="abc">one more extra div </div>

    <h1 id="head3">Example 3</h1>
    <div class="abc"> an extra div</div>
    <div class="abc"> one more extra div </div>

   <h1 id="head4"> Example 4</h1>
  <div class="abc"> an extra div </div>
  <div class="abc">an one more extra div </div>

  </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Below is my code:

```
    Elements contElements = document.select("main-content");
     for(Element e :  contElements) {
        if(e.tagName().equals("h1") &&     (!e.attr("id").equals("head1") &&    !e.attr("id").equals("head2")){
    //remove h1 element with other id and all  div's after this h1 element
     document.select("h1 ~ div ");
     e.remove();
  }
 else {
      //keep h1 element and the first div comes after h1 and   remove all other divs comes after this h1
    document.select("h1 ~ div");
  }
```

But the above code snippet is not working as expected. What else am missing to achieve the expected output.?

My Expected output:

```
  <html>
    <head>  </head>
    <body>
    <div ID="main-content">
      <div class="abc"> sample data </div>

      <h1 id="head1">Example 1</h1>
      <div class="abc"> 
         <table> <tr><td> table data</td></tr></table>
      </div>

     <h1 id="head2">Example 2 </h1>
      <div class="abc"> 
        <table> <tr><td> table data</td></tr></table>
      </div>

     </div>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css selectors instead of explicit looping.

Select and remove all `h1` elements whose `id` is not `#head1` **and** not `#head2`:

```
document.select("#main-content h1:not(#head1):not(#head2)").remove();
```

Select and remove all `div` elements that are not immediately preceded by an `h1`:

```
document.select("#main-content div:not(h1 + div)").remove();
```

If you only want to operate on immediate descendants of `#main-content`, put `>` right after it.